# Simple way to drag and drop text into textarea on Safari

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a simple way to implement drag and drop for Safari or is not supported?

I've been only able to listen for events when the element is dropped to the target textarea. The main problem is I am not able to detect the exact position where the draggable text was dropped, and just works by appending it at the end of the textarea.

From this answer I managed to add the text:

[Allow drag text and drop it in html input field without clearing previous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783221/allow-drag-text-and-drop-it-in-html-input-field-without-clearing-previous-data) (only works on Safari)

The drag and drop is done natively somehow on Chrome and Firefox (this last one **requires the entire text is selected** and set to draggable).
I'd like to know if there is a trick for web-kit so it just works like the Firefox trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Implement Firefox trick.** (Not tested without selecting via JS all the draggable text)

Detect via JS if Safari browser is being used and if so perform the following:

1. Remove draggable attribute from the draggable element:

   `item.removeAttribute('draggable')`
2. Add the Safari proper draggable attribute:

   `item.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-user-drag:element;')`

**Safari example of proper draggable element:**

```
<span style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">DRAGGABLE TEXT</span>
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/DragAndDrop.html